# ES6 import/export in test.js when debugging using vs code extension for jest fails with "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"

Tags: javascript, jestjs, es6-modules

I followed this https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-add-babel-integration-with-jest?pl=testing-javascript-with-jest-a36c4074 to setup babel + jest to use ES6 import/export in test.js. yarn run jest works, but I cannot debug using jest ext in vs code. And, get `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`. adding a package.json with `{type:"module"}` isn't working

**File structure-**

```
my-project 
    __tests__
          package.json (with `{type:"module"}`)
          abc.test.js
    src
    package.json
    jest.config.js 
    babel.config.json
```

**babel.config.js -**

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [["@babel/preset-env", { targets: { node: "current" } }]],
};
```

Comment: What is your file structure like?
Try installing this: babel-jest @babel/core @babel/preset-env with npm or yarn.
Follow this==> https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started#using-babel

Comment: updated with file structure. and i have all the above dependencies already installed

Comment: Did you update your `.babelrc` file too? what do you see now?

Comment: added to the post. ty :)

Comment: have not been able to get it running - just to let everyone know. so you can help

Comment: Oh really I thought you had solved this? I just checked your post and saw your update now. `presets` isn't enough. You need to add the targets... add this to yout `.babelrc` file ===>                                                               {
    "presets": [
        [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            {
                "targets": {
                    "node": "current"
                }
            }
        ]
    ]}

Comment: So, I added the targets with node=current too. but yarn run jest works fine. but not the debugging

Comment: What do you mean "not debugging" ...could you be clearer?

Comment: in your vscode, you can install the extension called "Jest" and then, it allows you to click on "debug" that shows in your test.js now for every test - this is how I'm debugging the test